# HA Proxy simple forwarding with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, haproxy

I am attempting to learn how to forward http traffic with HA Proxy.  To get started I thought I would use Docker and have come stuck.

The forwarding traffic im attempting to do looks like this

```
ha-proxy container port 81
>>> forward to
nginx container port 8088
```

When I load the ha proxy container from my browser with the url http://localhost:81/  The error message I get is

`503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request.`

> My setup looks like the following.

**nginx - container**

When I load http://localhost:8088/ I get the correct `Welcome to nginx!` home page.

Docker command im using for that is.  Im using `--net=host` so it binds it the host network.

```
docker run --name myapp-backend -p 8088:80 -d --net=host  nginx:1.15.0-alpine
```

**Ha Proxy**

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM haproxy:alpine
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

*haproxy.cfg*

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout 5000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000

frontend http-in
    bind *:81
    acl myapp-frontend hdr(host) -i localhost
    use_backend myapp-backend if myapp-frontend

backend myapp-backend
    balance roundrobin
    option http-server-close
    server myapp-server-1 localhost:8088 check
```

*Starting HA Proxy*

```
   docker build -t rob-haproxy .
   docker run --name ha-proxy -p 81:81  --net=host -d rob-haproxy
```

My thinking is that I have something wrong with the ha proxy config file haproxy.cfg. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Change  `    server myapp-server-1 localhost:8088 check`  to  `    server myapp-server-1 your_host_ip:8088 check`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went down the route of adding it to its own docker network as per Miq suggestion.  However this was not enough on its own so I also simplified the ha config.

Below is what it looks like now

```
global
  quiet

defaults
  mode http
  maxconn 5000

  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client  20s
  timeout server  20s

frontend public
    bind *:81
    default_backend apps

backend apps
    server myapp-backend myapp-backend:80 check
```

bash

```
docker network create elk || true
docker run --name myapp-backend -p 8088:80 -d --net=elk  nginx:1.15.0-alpine
docker run --name rob-haproxy -p 81:81 --net=dev-d rob-haproxy-image
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `localhost` in haproxy config file. For haproxy, `localhost` means `my container`, not your host. Instead `localhost`, use the nginx's docker service or container name. Of course place both containers in this same docker network.

Comment: Or host ip in this case